# Speech Recognizer not working when called normally other than button event like onClick

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition

I have in my program Speech Recognizer and when I run the startListening method directly in onCreate method Speech Recognizer doesn't seem working.
But when I place startListening method in button onClick method the Speech Recognizer working. I want Speech Recognizer method startListening directly invoked as shown in below program.

Following is my program.

```
       SpeechRecognizer mSpeechRecognizer;
Intent mSpeechRecognizerIntent;
TextView textView;
String speakId = "one";
String oldId = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_robo);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);


    mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE,
            Locale.getDefault());


    mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int error) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle results) {
            ArrayList<String> matches = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
            textView.setText(matches.get(0));

            //displaying the first match
            //if (matches != null)
            //processResult(matches.get(0));
        }

        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {

        }
    });

    /*
        below SpeechRecognizer does not start listening when called in MainActivity.
         */

    mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);


}
```

}

But when i call mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent) inside the button onClick event the SpeechRecognizer is working.

```
    public void Listen(View view) {
    mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
}
```

why when the code is placed in onCreate method and not inside the onClick method is not working.
Please tell a solution for that.

Comment: Speech Recognizer doesn't work even if it's working, where is the issue :') ahaha

Comment: call `startListening` inside `readyforspeech()` method

Comment: see at the bottom of the code when startListening method does not start the speech recognizer.

Comment: i have .used startListening inside readyforspeech() it is still not working

Comment: For those who are trying on Android 11, add this <manifest ...>
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.speech.RecognitionService" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just set used setRecognitionListener right after the createSpeechRecognizer  and the code is working.

```
    mSpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    mSpeechRecognizer.setRecognitionListener(recognitionListener);

    mSpeechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    mSpeechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE,
            Locale.getDefault());
```

and then called

```
 mSpeechRecognizer.startListening(mSpeechRecognizerIntent);
```

It works without using a button event.

RecogniserListener class should be declared this way.

```
    RecognitionListener recognitionListener = new RecognitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int error) {
            String message;
            switch (error) {
                case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_AUDIO:
                    message = "Audio recording error";
                    break;
                case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_CLIENT:
                    message = "Client side error";
                    break;
                case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS:
                    message = "Insufficient permissions";
                    break;
                case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK:
                    message = "Network error";
                    break;
                case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NETWORK_TIMEOUT:
                    message = "Network timeout";
                    break;
                case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_NO_MATCH:
                    message = "No match";
                    break;
                case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY:
                    message = "RecognitionService busy";
                    break;
                case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SERVER:
                    message = "error from server";
                    break;
                case SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT:
                    message = "No speech input";
                    break;
                default:
                    message = "Didn't understand, please try again.";
                    break;
            }
            textView.setText(message);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle results) {
            ArrayList<String> matches = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
            textView.setText(matches.get(0));

            //displaying the first match
            //if (matches != null)
                //processResult(matches.get(0));
        }

        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {

        }


};
```

Comment: There is an issue with a missing parentheses in your answer
see: new RecognitionListener() { ...
I am still voting up though because I had a difference situation than the question (that of getting the code to work on the main thread) that this helped answer.

Answer (score 0):

Rooted Device can behave differently, check in non rooted device.

For Non rooted devices

onRmsChanged can throw a error,
So add a Log atleast in all methods of RecognitionListener.